# run Spark Kafka wordcount.java example without "run-example" script

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-spark

I am trying to run the word count example in Spark, which will stream data from Kafka. 
[Source Code Here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/examples/JavaKafkaWordCount.java) . However, I found that the Cloudera Spark distribution is a bit different from the incubator one. I have no problem running spark shell and run word count example from there. However, there is no "run-example" script in the bin folder, which is indicated in the example source-code.

```
* Example:
 *    `./bin/run-example org.apache.spark.streaming.examples.JavaKafkaWordCount local[2]     zoo01,zoo02,
 *    zoo03 my-consumer-group topic1,topic2 1`
```

I am fairly new to jar but I know, to run a java program in command line, you need to package up all the dependencies and the code, compile and put into a jar file. And then run the jar file as a whole, which I guess, is what the "[run-example](https://github.com/apache/incubator-spark/blob/master/bin/run-example)" code will do.

Can anyone tell me how can I run the KafkaWordCount.java example without the run-example script?

A similar [question](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/How-do-I-run-the-examples/td-p/6813) here, but I don't want to run the java code in spark-shell every time.

Many thanks.

Hadoop:
I have a Cloudera Hadoop Distribution(CDH 4.6.0-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.26) which managed by Cloudera Manager,

Spark:
I've downloaded the (SPARK 0.9.0-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.50) parcel and also distribute and activated this service.

Kafka: 
kafka-0.8.0, I have downloaded the source and bulit it from the source.

Answer (score 0):

I would have JavaKafkaWordCount.java [built using Maven](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#standalone-applications), package it into a Jar file, and [use spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) to run it.